# Laravel Stripe Cashier to Delete a Customer

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

How do I delete a customer in Stripe using Laravel's Cashier built-in method?

I know there's a way to delete a customer through Stripe's API - https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/delete But I want to use Laravel's Cashier method because it is much cleaner in my code instead of creating another code to use Guzzle in working on Stripe API.

Any help or tips is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
private function deleteStripeCustomer($user): void
{
    if ($user->stripe_id) {
        $user->asStripeCustomer()->delete();
    }
}
```

this will works

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a delete method for Customers with [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#customers). You'll need to make that API call to Stripe directly.